Why do evacuations result in so many injuries?
Evacuations often end in several minor and sometimes serious injuries, why is this? What are the most common causes? I've never done it, but I struggle to imagine how sliding down an inflatable can cause so many issues.

Take 150 random people of all ages and medical conditions from a shopping mall out into the parking lot and put them on a playground slide and see how things go.

What Steve said. Like, me, I'm gonna be fine hurling myself down even a fairly steep slide with a bad landing site at a moment's notice. Put my 60-something mother on there, I'm not so sure. My aunt, who already has physical problems, is almost certain to be injured on it even given plenty of time to prepare.

Dozens to hundreds of animals suddenly panicked and herded towards traffic choke points. In nature we call this a stampede. For humans, its an evacuation.

@DavidS: animals don't obstruct the stampede by trying to bring their carry-on with them.

@DarthPseudonym: even professional athletes get sometimes hurt when warming up or doing other non-intense movements.

In most martial arts and gymnastics you are generally 'taught' how to fall and frequently an ongoing practice.

Evacuation is intended to happen within 90 seconds. For comparison, have you ever measured how looong it takes for everybody to leave the plane when there is no problem at all, the plane sits comfortably at the finger and everybody is extremely eager to get out (e.g., because the landing was delayed) and even if hardly anybody has hand luggage? Heck, it typically takes 5 minutes until the person standing in the aisle and blocking me from getting up is able to move a single step forward ...

The exprerience is far from playground slides. The evacation slides are very slippery and thus quick so the landing is not necessarily graceful. Also as hundreds of passengers are required to evacuate within very short time frame, the slides are filled with people bouncing to each other. Typical injuries include fractured ankles and collarbones. Also in case of fire and smoke events there are respiratory injuries due to smoke inhalation.
Here is a video about evacuation certification 



One of the most challenging tasks during A380 development was to design the upper deck slides such that they would stay stiff even when loaded with lots of people on them and to limit the speed at which people arrive on the ground. +1

I'd also point out that the landing site on a playground slide is generally clear and flat, and likely sand or pea gravel to absorb some impact. An airline slide will dump you out onto tarmac or smooth grass if you're lucky, but there's no guarantees it won't be uneven and/or rocky. And even tarmac can take the skin off your calves if you aren't ready for it.

PANIC. Note there are many injuries also when fire alarm and evacuation is performed in buildings, plazas, and concerts. Crow management is difficult. Close spaces creates more panic (so same problems with less people).

About 5.45 on that video, if you keep a close eye on the left hand slide, you'll see one of the cabin crew - the very last to evacuate - having a fairly violent tumble.

I just assumed that it's very similar to the UK sport of cheese rolling.

@PeterKämpf I also remember reading there was a speculation that people would not dare to slide down from the upper deck.

There is no valid answer for this question unless you take a specific example of evacuation with injuries.
The only obvious factor to injuries is scare and loss of composure. Of course some persons are more exposed than other when dealing with fast and unusual actions, including the elderly and the already injured.

But for a person in good fit an emergency slide is not dangerous by itself. You could use it a whole day long for amusement, and you wouldn't be injured.
Each evacuation is a specific case, passengers will be confronted to different dangers and hazards in different evacuation types, e.g.:

On the flat runway stop area after a slight runway excursion.

After a water landing.

While there is already a fire in the cabin

After a crash in mountainous area, etc.


There are usually no injuries in an evacuation test in the hangar of the manufacturer with people, who are manufacturer's workers relatives, prepared for the evacuation without any baggage and with no actual emergency. If you know your life isn't threatened you are more willing to take care of what you do and do to others.
It also depends on the nationality of the passengers. There are citizen from several countries that are used to be very patient and disciplined, even when their life is threatened. This is also true for some professions. Evacuating a military aircraft may be different from evacuating a civilian aircraft. On the other hand in some countries, e.g. in my own country, more people are rather selfish and know better than crew members about what to do and where to put priorities.
People with luggage (in spite of being told not to take them), people rushing and pushing other persons waiting to leave the plane, people with babies in their hands, etc, are potentially adding danger for themselves or for others.
Is that different from what you would see when a building is in fire and residents use a simple stair to evacuate it? Would that be different using a simple slide at the pool under the pressure of an emergency?

Untrained people are thrown into a sudden, confusing, dangerous, situation they're not prepared for.
Of course there are going to be injuries. This is not specific to aircraft evacuations, evacuations of office buildings (even practice evacuations, regularly lead to injuries. So do evacuations of trains, buses, ships, anywhere where a group of people without prior training is told to quickly leave the area.
Throw in the already hazardous (even to trained staff) surroundings and accidents become even more likely (think the case some years ago where an evacuating passenger got out of the aircraft uninjured and then ran headlong into an approaching fire truck and was killed for example).

I think you're thinking of this https://edition.cnn.com/2014/01/15/us/asiana-crash-new-video/index.html - she didn't run headlong into a firetruck, quite the opposite - the firetruck ploughed headlong into her when she was already unconscious on the ground!

Another point to consider is that if passengers were never injured in evacuations, that would strongly suggest that evacuation procedures are slower than they should be to maximize the number of people who escape alive.

@Jamiec and some reports suggested the fire crew laughed about it...

The only purpose of evacuation is getting as much people out alive in shortest time possible. If they can walk afterwards, it is considered an optional extra.
During evacuation you want to move people from possibly lethal location to much safer location. The focus is on survival, not comfort. Being in a posibly lethal position is very stressful and very few people can handle that even after many trainings.
Adding stressed crowd to rush and unusual physical activity without prior warning assures little nuisances like dislocated joint, broken bone or scratch.

If most couldn't walk afterwards, you'd have a problem clearing the bottom.  The acceptable rate of crippling injuries has to be fairly low to allow people to reach safety (right next to a burning plane isn't safety)
